# Azure Logout Async

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, uwp

I am trying to force a logout from an azure server. If you click to logout and then click login, you're not prompted for your username/password it just logs you straight back in.

I am writing a UWP application that connects to an Azure Webserver. If it is relevant you can see that when you Logout it removes the reference from the Windows Credential Manager and restores it as soon as you click you Login.

My questions is essentially, what else do I need to remove to stop the app retrieving the previous credentials instead of prompting so a new user can sign in?

```
    public async Task LogoutAsync()
    {
        if (Client.CurrentUser == null || Client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken == null)
            return;


        // Invalidate the token on the mobile backend
        var authUri = new Uri($"{Client.MobileAppUri}/.auth/logout");
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", Client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
            await httpClient.GetAsync(authUri);
        }


        // Remove the token from the cache
        _loginProvider.RemoveTokenFromSecureStore();

        // Remove the token from the MobileServiceClient
        await Client.LogoutAsync();
    }

    public async Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync()
    {

        Client.CurrentUser = _loginProvider.RetrieveTokenFromSecureStore();

        if (Client.CurrentUser != null && !IsTokenExpired(Client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken))
        {
            // User has previously been authenticated, return current authenticated user
            return Client.CurrentUser;
        }

        if (Client.CurrentUser != null && IsTokenExpired(Client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken))
        {
            // Token is expired so perform a Logout
            await LogoutAsync();
        }

        // We need to ask for credentials at this point
        await _loginProvider.LoginAsync(Client).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (Client.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            // We were able to successfully log in, store token for authenticated user
            _loginProvider.StoreTokenInSecureStore(Client.CurrentUser);
        }
        return Client.CurrentUser;
    }
```

I should add that the code (I didn't write the original program) seems to be based off this link https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/. The original App didn't have a method to allow the user to logout so this was only called when the token expired.

Comment: Does the `RemoveTokenFromSecureStore` method not work?

Comment: It does work and it does remove the token, the token is just restored automatically when you rerun the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case forming the question on SO has led me to answer my own question.

The login screen it gives you includes a webview that saves cookies. Forcing these to be cleared has solved my problem. I have also cleared the token cache although I don't think this actually solves the problem in all cases on its own.

If I call this function before I invalidate the backend token then it works as intended and when clicking to login I am prompted for my username and password.

```
    public void RemoveAuthenticationInfo()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
        authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

        Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        var cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager;
        HttpCookieCollection myCookieJar = cookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri(Authority));
        foreach (HttpCookie cookie in myCookieJar)
        {
            cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
```